# Создание меню в Toolbar. Есть ли еще варианты помимо использования drawable.xml?

Tags: java, android

В написании проекта столкнулся с такой ситуацией. У меня есть несколько активити и в каждой из них есть однотипный toolbar. Я не хочу в каждом из них прописывать одни и те же строки и поэтому я создал абстрактный класс BaseActivity. Метод onCreate в нем работает на отлично, но вот метод onCreateOptionsMenu почему-то не хочет показывать мне мои 3 правые иконки в каждой активити, унаследовавших от BaseActivity. Этот метод просто в null!
Есть ли другая возможность создания menu, или же что-то нужно дописать, чтобы иконки показывались все-таки?
Само меню создал классическим способом - через drawable с прописанием item.
Код абстрактного класса:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Приложите код абстрактного класса

Comment: Добавил правкой сверху

Comment: На момент вызова `findViewById(R.id.toolbar)` макет ещё не установлен (не было вызова `setContentView(...)` - поэтому тулбар здесь не найден и не установлен.

Comment: @woesss, извиняюсь, на момент написания ответа, вашего комментария не было:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В методе onCreate() у вас нет метода setContentView(), вы не получаете ваше View из layout, и поэтому findViewById(R.Id.toolbar), не может найти ваш toolbar

Сделайте как тут, только вместо R.layout.acyivity_fragment установите свой layout

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
    }
```

P.s. не забудьте, что для каждой активити вам нужно устанавливать свой layout, думаю проще оставить в абстрактном классе только onCreateOptionsMenu(), а onCreate() прописывать в самих классах Activity, т.к.для каждой активити метод может сильно отличаться.